# Homeomorphism between 2 Sets

Tags: general-topology

How can I show that $SL(n,R)$ is homeomorphic to $SO(n,r) \times R^{n^2+n-2}/2$?
Here $SO(n,R)$ denotes the set of all real orthogonal nxn matrices with positive determinant.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a consequence of the Gram-Schmidt orthonormalization process. Given a matrix $X\in\text{SL}(n,r)$, apply the Gram-Schmidt process to the sequence of its columns, obtaining an orthonormal sequence of column vectors, which are the columns of a matrix that I'll call $p(X)\in\text{SO}(n,r)$. This function $p:\text{SL}(n,r)\to\text{SO}(n,r)$ is the first component of the desired homeomorphism.  The second component, $\text{SL}(n,r)\to\mathbb R^{(n^2+n-2)/2}$, will keep track of the various coefficients that you had to multiply and divide vectors by during the application of the Gram-Schmidt process. There remains the task of counting the relevant coefficients, hoping that there are $(n^2+n-2)/2$ of them, to account for the exponent in the question. I leave that task to you (i.e., I'm too lazy to do it myself).

Answer (score 1):

This is a special case of so called *Iwasawa decomposition*: $SL(n,R)=O(n,R)\cdot B$, where $B$ is the group of real upper triangular matrices.